# In IOS, where to add the search display controller in view controller

Tags: ios

I created a tableview and displayed all the table related items there. Then i declared search display controller and search bar. 
I added the search bar in Search display view controller.
But i dont know where to add this Search display view controller, whether in the tableview or in the self.view? 
Can you guide me in this?

Answer (score 1):

once you have added your SearchView to the ui using Storyboard i suppose? you can create a delegate for the searchbar. as you would for a tableview within a view, your controller then needs to implement searchbardelegate. Thats what worked for me :)

Comment: Am sorry, i am not using storyboard concept. I am doing everything in coding only..

Comment: No, am working with .m and .h file only... Have to learn after this.. Thank you, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about "controllers", Then We also must talk about NavigationControllers. So - Firstly, You must have a `UINavigationController` as window.rootViewController. Then You probably pushed some kind `UIViewController`, in which You declared tableview.  Now - If You want to see search view controller - You declare it's controller class instance and push it on your main navigationController stack. Is that enough info, or You need some more guidance?

Comment: Ah, got it sir. I have to add it as you said along with table view. Thank you....